# Google AI Document Enhance Extraction Result

Tags: google-cloud-platform, ocr, google-ai-platform, cloud-document-ai

I am new to Google AI Document. I saw there is a Human-in-the-loop mechanism that allows people to review the extracted results. Will the extracted result which has been manually updated (by a human being) be sent back to the document processor for processing again (a second time)?

Answer (score 0):

FYI, Document AI has an actively monitored tag [`[cloud-document-ai]`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/cloud-document-ai)

---

[Human-in-the-Loop](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/hitl) doesn't directly update the models to improve performance, it allows review/correction of output from the Document AI processor.

However, you can use the output from Human-in-the-Loop to perform [Uptraining](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/training-overview#uptrain) on supported processors. You can import the human reviewed [`Documents`](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/reference/rest/v1/Document) into Document AI Workbench as training data to create custom versions of processors with improved accuracy for specific use cases.

Here's videos with more information about Custom Processors and Human-in-the-Loop.

- [What is Document AI Workbench?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLIivdWyY5sqIR88BxIK-3w14Vm-jTH1id&v=BkE69dM0G-w)
- [What is Human-in-the-Loop?](https://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PLIivdWyY5sqIR88BxIK-3w14Vm-jTH1id&v=qeuRQAityB8)